# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.preventDefault') in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hope you're all good.

I'm having an issue I can't find a concise answer on so I'm going to ask for help here.

I have a function which I'm trying to call in my React Component:

```
  // Open up calendar day if today is equal to day in API.
  const [openCalendarBox, setOpenCalendarBox] = useState('');

  // Call on post method via axios
  const openCalendarChocolateBox = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (date) {
      // Url where to post
      await axios.post(`http://localhost:5001/open/chocolate`, {
        day: date,
      });

      alert('New day is available to eat!');
    }

    setOpenCalendarBox('');
  };

  openCalendarChocolateBox();
```

But when I call the function it doesn't work like it's suppose to, I'm instead getting this error in the console:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.preventDefault')
```

How do I solve this issue? I tried removing the event parameter in my argument but I still want to prevent the page from reloading more than once or at all when calling on my function.

Thanks for any help in advance, take care guys.

Comment: Well, it's undefined because you're not passing an event in. Consider attaching it to an event listener and passing in an event either via JS or HTML.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for helping out. I just want to load it without an event listener, is there an event listener for when the component loads? I don't want it to be handled by an event but when the user loads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load this when the component loads, you don't need an event listener. Simply move the code to a `useEffect()` hook with an empty dependency array (will only run when component loads).

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (date) {
      // Url where to post
      await axios.post(`http://localhost:5001/open/chocolate`, {
        day: date,
      });

      alert('New day is available to eat!');
    }

    setOpenCalendarBox('');
}, [])
```

New problem though, where is `date` coming from?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm getting date from this code a few lines above: const current = new Date();
  // Retrieve current day of the month
  const date = current.getDate();  :)